# python: creating list from string

Tags: python, string, list

I have list of strings

```
a = ['word1, 23, 12','word2, 10, 19','word3, 11, 15']
```

I would like to create a list

```
b = [['word1',23,12],['word2', 10, 19],['word3', 11, 15]]
```

Is this a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
input = ['word1, 23, 12','word2, 10, 19','word3, 11, 15']
output = []
for item in input:
    items = item.split(',')
    output.append([items[0], int(items[1]), int(items[2])])
```

Comment: @Oliver I'm not sure if you are being serious or not!  ;-) Doesn't seem all that Pythonic. List comprehensions have their place but they can be overdone in my view. Or perhaps that's just my lack of familiarity with them.

Comment: Definitely serious! It's very readable. I think this is a classic example where list comprehensions *can* be used, but in the end are not the best way to go.

Comment: It's a matter of style I guess, I much prefer the list comprehension!

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
b = [ entry.split(',') for entry in a ]
b = [ b[i] if i % 3 == 0 else int(b[i]) for i in xrange(0, len(b)) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

More concise than others:

```
def parseString(string):
    try:
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return string

b = [[parseString(s) for s in clause.split(', ')] for clause in a]
```

---

Alternatively if your format is fixed as `<string>, <int>, <int>`, you can be even more concise:

```
def parseClause(a,b,c):
    return [a, int(b), int(c)]

b = [parseClause(*clause) for clause in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert some of them to numbers and don't know in advance which ones, some additional code will be needed. Try something like this:

```
b = []
for x in a:
    temp = []
    items = x.split(",")
    for item in items:
        try:
            n = int(item)
        except ValueError:
            temp.append(item)
        else:
            temp.append(n)
    b.append(temp)
```

This is longer than the other answers, but it's more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but here's a one liner list comprehension:

```
data = ['word1, 23, 12','word2, 10, 19','word3, 11, 15']

[[int(item) if item.isdigit() else item for item in items.split(', ')] for items in data]
```

or

```
[int(item) if item.isdigit() else item for items in data for item in items.split(', ')]
```